# Openvpn authentication fail caused by wrong system date time

Tags: linux, openvpn, authentication, openssl

I have a **remote** linux device connected as an openvpn client to an openvpn server over TCP, 
with standard certificate authentication.
Unfortunately this device **has lost the current system Date Time**, which now is 2000-01-01 00:00:00. This cause the **certificate authentication** to fail.

Is there any method to **avoid the server checking the certificate**, or the Date Time, or other things, just to let me reach the device and setting the correct date time?

Comment: Have you tried `--client-cert-not-required`? (Read the man page for important information regarding this option.)